# How to set background-image property from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set `background-image` property using JavaScript.

The problem is, I got image links like:

```
https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Pkmq1nm3skO0-j693JTMd7RL0Zk=/0x0:2012x1341/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg
```

When I try to set this link to style, it can't handle some characters I think.

```
<div style='background-image: url(urlString);'
```

Is there any way to handle these characters or do I need to add `background-image` using some other way?

Comment: What does this have to do with JS? Looks like you're using an inline style attribute in HTML.

Comment: Your title clearly says you want to do thsi from JavaScript, but the content of your question only shows HTML and an inline style. Do you need to do this in an inline style, or through JavaScript, or via a stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes around [CSS strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/string) in [`url(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url):

```
<div style='background-image: url("https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Pkmq1nm3skO0-j693JTMd7RL0Zk=/0x0:2012x1341/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg");'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it like this:

```
var div = document.querySelector(...); // select the div
div.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + urlString + "')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('your cdn path')";
```

This is a code sippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/fnwjhgzw/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var imageURL = 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Pkmq1nm3skO0-j693JTMd7RL0Zk=/0x0:2012x1341/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg';


var imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
imageElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+imageURL+"')";
```

```css
#image {
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`element.style.backgroundImage="url('image name')";` should be used. Here element is a variable. If you want to set the background image of the web page then use `document.body` instead of element in the code.